# How to access ansible facts in roles?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts, ansible-role

I am currently working on some ansible automation tasks and wanted to use ansible facts in a role I created. However, I cannot access any facts.
Example:
If I want to use the default IP-Address of a Windows machine, I was advised to use the following variable:

```
{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}
```

Ansible however tells me, that this variable is not defined.

Does anyone have an idea as to how I should use facts in a role?

Comment: You need to gather facts before using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one:
{{ hostvars[host].ansible_default_ipv4.address }}